# Is there a way to launch an iPhone app without user intervention at a given time/day on iOS4

Tags: iphone, ios4

I would like to launch an app into the background on a given day/time to perform some background task.  Using LocalNotifications doesn't seem to cut it because the user has to respond to the notification in order to launch the app.   Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: LocalNotifications are the closest you will get to this without a jailbreak.

Comment: I'd like to see this... launching the iHome app at a scheduled time would be awesome!

Comment: It'll be cool until advertisements start popping up! :)

Comment: ok thanks. How about this then. Once the application is launched, can I programmatically send it into the background? In other words, the user hits the 'alert.action' button of the notification, the app launches and immediately goes into the background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS doesn't support this. If you're updating some values, you can do that on next launch. Perhaps you can run some update at your service at a scheduled time, if you're running a service. Beyond that I'm not sure -- it'd depend on your requirements.

Comment: ok thanks. How about this then.  Once the application is launched, can I programmatically send it into the background?  In other words, the user hits the 'alert.action' button of the notification, the app launches and immediately goes into the background.

Answer (score 1):

No. Third-party applications can only be launched or brought to the foreground by user interaction.